# How can we set a general publish setting for a Flash projects?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5.5

In Flash 5.5 you can create flash projects which allow you to share libraries of flash files in production time. It also allow you to publish all the files together.

I want when I publish all the flash fla documents, the output swf files save to a specific folder. 
I cant find a way to make this automatic, so if you have 200 files, you need to go to each of the fla document and change its publish setting. which kinda ruin all the projects' usefulness...

might be possible to do it using jsfl. however prefer to do it some other way so i our artists team can keep working in a same way as before.

Thanks a lot for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes JSFL can do this for you. I'll give you an example and try to comment in the jsfl code as best I can to explain what is happening. Feel free to ask any clarifying questions.

So let's assume you have a folder on your computer that contains many other folders that all hold FLA files. This code will loop through all folders in that main containing folder, let's call it "allFLAs", then output them to a folder called "allSWFs". The code below will keep the original folders from allFLAs inside of allSWFs. So if a FLA file was at allFLAs/group1/file1.fla then in allSWFs would have allSWFs/group1/file1.swf. This is so if you have files with same name that they will not overwrite one another. You can just remove the + dirList[n] from the exportSWF line and it would put all SWFs into the main allSWFs folder.

This code does not alter the publish settings for any of the files that it runs and it closes the Flash IDE when it is finished.

```
// Main folder that holds the folders containing all the FLA files.
var folder = 'file:///C:/path/to/main/folder/allFLAs';

if (!null) {
    // Create an array of all the folders that are contained in our main folder.
    var dirList = FLfile.listFolder(folder, 'directories');
    // Loop through each item in the array to find each FLA file.
    for (var n = 0; n<dirList.length; ++n) {
        // Create an array of all FLA files in the directory list array.
        var list = FLfile.listFolder(folder+'/'+ dirList[n] + '/*.fla', 'files');
        fl.outputPanel.trace('file:///C:/path/to/output/folder/allSWFs/'+ dirList[n]);
        // Create containing folder for this file based on the name of the folder in the directory list array, in the new output folder.
        FLfile.createFolder('file:///C:/path/to/output/folder/allSWFs/'+ dirList[n]);
        var flaName;
        var swfName;
        for (var i = 0; i<list.length; ++i) {
            flaName = list[i];
            swfName = list[i].split('.')[0]+'.swf';
            fl.outputPanel.trace(flaName+' exported as '+swfName);
            // open the document, publish to SWF, and close without saving.
            fl.openDocument(folder+'/'+ dirList[n] +'/'+flaName);
            fl.getDocumentDOM().exportSWF('file:///C:/path/to/output/folder/allSWFs/'+ dirList[n] + '/'+swfName, true);
            fl.closeDocument(fl.getDocumentDOM(), false);
        }
    }
}
fl.quit()
```